# Is there a way to include certain data in the body of all axios requests by default?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

For example: I want to always send the user's email address and some other data with each axios request.  I was looking at global axios defaults but I don't see a way to include defaults for the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  config.params.email = 'xx@xx.xx'
  return config;
}, function (error) {
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

You can add common parameters to request interception.

Comment: That was a major help.  I changed it to config.data.email and got it in the body of the post request.  I'm gonna do my homework on these interceptors.  Thanks alot.